# I cannot figure out why this isn't working on the random side

Tags: variables, random

I am in a computer science 101 class and I'm attempting to create things based on what I have learned.

I created this very basic dungeons and dragons npc creator to allow for me to learn how to use lists, decision making, some loop usage. I know the code isn't pretty but I'm in week 4.

I'm attempting to have a random side to the program as well as a user input side. My user input side works as intended, but the random is giving me variable not defined errors. Even though it's using the same code.

```
import random

# Races
raceslist = ['Dragonborn (black)', 'Dragonborn (Blue)', 'Dragonborn (Brass)', 'Dragonborn (Bronze)',
             'Dragonborn (Copper)', 'Dragonborn (Gold)', 'Dragonborn (Green)', 'Dragonborn (Red)',
             'Dragonborn (Silver)', 'Dragonborn (White)', 'Dwarf', 'Hill Dwarf', 'Elf', 'High Elf', 'Drow',
             'Wood Elf', 'Gnome', 'Rock Gnome', 'Half-Elf', 'Half-Orc', 'Halfling', 'Human', 'Tiefling']

races = {
    '1': 'Dragonborn (black)',
    '2': 'Dragonborn (Blue)',
    '3': 'Dragonborn (Brass)',
    '4': 'Dragonborn (Bronze)',
    '5': 'Dragonborn (Copper)',
    '6': 'Dragonborn (Gold)',
    '7': 'Dragonborn (Green)',
    '8': 'Dragonborn (Red)',
    '9': 'Dragonborn (Silver)',
    '10': 'Dragonborn (White)',
    '11': 'Dwarf',
    '12': 'Hill Dwarf',
    '13': 'Elf',
    '14': 'High Elf',
    '15': 'Drow',
    '16': 'Wood Elf',
    '17': 'Gnome',
    '18': 'Rock Gnome',
    '19': 'Half-Elf',
    '20': 'Half-Orc',
    '21': 'Halfling',
    '22': 'Human',
    '23': 'Tiefling',
}

# Classes
classes = {
    '1': 'Barbarian',
    '2': 'Bard',
    '3': 'Cleric',
    '4': 'Druid',
    '5': 'Fighter',
    '6': 'Monk',
    '7': 'Paladin',
    '8': 'Ranger',
    '9': 'Rogue',
    '10': 'Sorceror',
    '11': 'Warlock',
    '12': 'Wizard'
}

classlist = ['Barbarian', 'Bard', 'Cleric', 'Druid', 'Fighter', 'Monk', 'Paladin',
             'Ranger', 'Rogue', 'Sorceror', 'Warlock', 'Wizard']

# Choosing Random Generation or Creation Guide
Startup = input('Would you like to use the random generation or choose yourself? (Random/Choose)').lower()

while not (Startup != 'random' or 'choose'):
    print('Please Try Input Again:')
    Startup = input('Would you like to use the random generation or choose yourself? (Random/Choose)').lower()

if Startup == 'random':
    race_choice = races[str(random.randint(1, 23))]
    class_choice = classes[str(random.randint(1, 12))]
    print('\n', race_choice, sep='')
    print(class_choice)

elif Startup == 'choose':
    print("\nGreat!\n\tNow let's choose a race to play\n")
    print('\n'.join(raceslist), sep='\n')
    race_choice = input('\nWhich race would you like to play?\n Please enter your race name:').lower()
    print('Awesome! Now what class 8would you like to play')
    print('\n'.join(classlist), sep='\n')
    class_choice = input('Please type in your class name:').lower()

# Ability Score Rolling

Dice_Rolls1 = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
Dice_Rolls1.sort()
del Dice_Rolls1[0]
Dice_Rolls1_added = Dice_Rolls1[0] + Dice_Rolls1[1] + Dice_Rolls1[2]

Dice_Rolls2 = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
Dice_Rolls2.sort()
del Dice_Rolls2[0]
Dice_Rolls2_added = Dice_Rolls2[0] + Dice_Rolls2[1] + Dice_Rolls2[2]

Dice_Rolls3 = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
Dice_Rolls3.sort()
del Dice_Rolls3[0]
Dice_Rolls3_added = Dice_Rolls3[0] + Dice_Rolls3[1] + Dice_Rolls3[2]

Dice_Rolls4 = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
Dice_Rolls4.sort()
del Dice_Rolls4[0]
Dice_Rolls4_added = Dice_Rolls4[0] + Dice_Rolls4[1] + Dice_Rolls4[2]

Dice_Rolls5 = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
Dice_Rolls5.sort()
del Dice_Rolls5[0]
Dice_Rolls5_added = Dice_Rolls5[0] + Dice_Rolls5[1] + Dice_Rolls5[2]

Dice_Rolls6 = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
Dice_Rolls1.sort()
del Dice_Rolls6[0]
Dice_Rolls6_added = Dice_Rolls6[0] + Dice_Rolls6[1] + Dice_Rolls6[2]

ability_scores = [Dice_Rolls1_added, Dice_Rolls2_added, Dice_Rolls3_added, Dice_Rolls4_added, Dice_Rolls5_added,
                  Dice_Rolls6_added]

# print(class_choice)
print('\nHere are your Dice Rolls:')
print(ability_scores)

# User Input
print('\nPlease Choose where your rolled Dice numbers will go.\n')
strength_input = int(input('What Dice Roll would you like to associate with Strength?'))
dexterity_input = int(input('What Dice Roll would you like to associate with Dexterity?'))
constitution_input = int(input('What Dice Roll would you like to associate with Constitution?'))
wisdom_input = int(input('What Dice Roll would you like to associate with Wisdom?'))
intelligence_input = int(input('What Dice Roll would you like to associate with Intellect?'))
charisma_input = int(input('What Dice Roll would you like to associate with Charisma?'))

# Racial Stat Attribution
while race_choice == '':
    Strength = strength_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Charisma = charisma_input

if race_choice == 'half-elf':
    askinput = input(
        '\nWhere would you like the +1 to go? (Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, Wisdom, Intelligence)').lower()
    if askinput == 'strength':
        Strength == strength_input + 1
        Dexterity = dexterity_input
        Constitution = constitution_input
        Intelligence = intelligence_input
        Wisdom = wisdom_input
        Charisma = charisma_input + 1

    elif askinput == 'dexterity':
        Strength = strength_input
        Dexterity = dexterity_input + 1
        Constitution = constitution_input
        Intelligence = intelligence_input
        Wisdom = wisdom_input
        Charisma = charisma_input + 1

    elif askinput == 'constitution':
        Strength = strength_input
        Dexterity = dexterity_input
        Constitution = constitution_input + 1
        Intelligence = intelligence_input
        Wisdom = wisdom_input
        Charisma = charisma_input + 1

    elif askinput == 'wisdom':
        Strength = strength_input
        Dexterity = dexterity_input
        Constitution = constitution_input
        Intelligence = intelligence_input
        Wisdom = wisdom_input + 1
        Charisma = charisma_input + 1

    elif askinput == 'intelligence':
        Strength = strength_input
        Dexterity = dexterity_input
        Constitution = constitution_input
        Intelligence = intelligence_input + 1
        Wisdom = wisdom_input
        Charisma = charisma_input + 1


elif race_choice == 'dwarf':
    Strength = strength_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Constitution = constitution_input + 2

elif race_choice == 'hill dwarf':
    Strength = strength_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Constition = constitution_input + 2
    Wisdom = wisdom_input + 1

elif race_choice == 'elf':
    Strength = strength_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input + 2

elif race_choice == 'high elf':
    Strength = strength_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input + 2
    Intelligence = intelligence_input + 1

elif race_choice == 'drow':
    Strength = strength_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Intelliegence = intelligence_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input + 2
    Charisma = charisma_input + 1

elif race_choice == 'wood elf':
    Strength = strength_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Intelliegence = intelligence_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input + 2
    Wisdom = wisdom_input + 1

elif race_choice == 'gnome':
    Strength = strength_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input + 2

elif race_choice == 'rock gnome':
    Strength = strength_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input + 2
    Constition = constitution_input + 1

elif race_choice == ("dragonborn (black)" or 'dragonborn (blue)' or 'dragonborn (brass)' or 'dragonborn (bronze)' or
                     'dragonborn (copper)' or 'dragonborn (gold)' or 'dragonborn (green)' or 'dragonborn (red)' or
                     'dragonborn (silver)' or 'dragonborn (white)'):
    Strength = strength_input + 2
    Dexterity = dexterity_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input
    Charisma = charisma_input + 1

elif race_choice == 'half-orc':
    Dexterity = dexterity_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Strength = strength_input + 2
    Constition = constitution_input + 1

elif race_choice == 'halfling':
    Strength = strength_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Intelligence = intelligence_input
    Charisma = charisma_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input + 2

elif race_choice == 'human':
    Strength = strength_input + 1
    Dexterity = dexterity_input + 1
    Constitution = constitution_input + 1
    Intelligence = intelligence_input + 1
    Wisdom = wisdom_input + 1
    Charisma = charisma_input + 1

elif race_choice == 'tiefling':
    Strength = strength_input
    Dexterity = dexterity_input
    Constitution = constitution_input
    Wisdom = wisdom_input
    Charisma = charisma_input + 2
    Intelligence = intelligence_input + 1

# Defining ability scores
STR = 'Strength'
DEX = 'Dexterity'
CON = 'Constitution'
WIS = 'Wisdom'
INT = 'Intellect'
CHA = 'Charisma'

# User Output
Getname = input('\nGreat, now choose a name:')
underlined_text = ('\x1B[4m' + Getname.title() + '\x1B[0m')
print('\nName: ', underlined_text, sep='')
print(race_choice.title(), ' - ', class_choice.title(), sep='')
print(STR, '=', Strength)
print(DEX, '=', Dexterity)
print(CON, '=', Constitution)
print(WIS, '=', Wisdom)
print(INT, '=', Intelligence)
print(CHA, '=', Charisma)


exitinput = input('Press Return to Exit:')
```

Updated with while code block. It's ugly and can be more efficient. But I'm using what I have learned in my class.

What confuses me is that if I do choose it works. But as soon as I go random nothing works as intended.

Comment: Please paste your *exact* code, the code as you pasted won't run, the elif for dwarf implies there's an if before it about race but that isn't in your code.

Comment: Sure give me a bit. Should I just send the whole code block then?

Comment: In the random block, you don't set the race & choice to lowercase, thus during attribution, none of them match. An easy fix is to set them to lowercase during random block assignment, ie, `race_choice = races[str(random.randint(1, 23))].lower()`

Comment: Omg. And I've been so diligent about doing that. Thanks for catching it! Fought with it for like 2 hours

Comment: Check your IDE for debugging features, it would help on figuring out bugs like these since you can verify what values are being compared, the path taken etc.